# Please let me know how can I remove the syntaxerror in this code

Tags: python, syntax

why I have syntax error for Sum=Sum+xn?

```
Sum=0
x1=int(input('insert a number= '))
x2=int(input('insert another number= '))
Sum=x1+x2
print('The Sum is:',Sum)
while True :
        Javab=input('would you adding another number? :(y/n)')
        if Javab=='y':
            xn=int(input('insert another number :')
            Sum=Sum+xn
            print('Sum is:', Sum)
        elif Javab=='n':
        break
else : print('Sum is:', Sum)
```

I need to calculate the summation of a sequences of numbers.

Comment: Count the parentheses in the line above.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The purpose of this site is to solve specific programming problems. If you want to learn the basics of programming, I suggest watching a [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfscVS0vtbw)

Comment: ChatGPT is very good to help with basic programming problems such as this one. It correctly says to add the parenthesis in the line before. Keep in mind to view its suggestions with a critical mind as they can be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**You are missing a parentheses in the line `xn=int(input('insert another number :')`.**

Change it to `xn=int(input('insert another number :'))` as shown:

```
Sum=0
x1=int(input('insert a number= '))
x2=int(input('insert another number= '))
Sum=x1+x2
print('The Sum is:',Sum)
while True :
    Javab=input('would you adding another number? :(y/n)')
    if Javab=='y':
        xn=int(input('insert another number :'))
        Sum=Sum+xn
        print('Sum is:', Sum)
    elif Javab=='n':
        break
else : print('Sum is:', Sum)
```

Note that syntax errors are *almost always* caused by the line above the line raising the error.